# When answering, what kind of examples and references can I use on this site?

Tags: support, faq, answers

When I answer a question I wonder what kind of examples and references I should use and, more importantly, shouldn't use on the site.
Should I post links to my own website of where I did X, or should I try to get majority of my answer from drupal.org? I'm worried that people will start advertising themselves, and if so, is this a bad thing?

Answer (score 1):

So long as the answer

- *answers the question*
- is more or less correct
- is mostly self-contained -- that is, it would still be enough to answer the question even if the referenced site is down or unavailable

Then I think it doesn't matter so much where the examples and references come from.

> Should I post links to my own website of where I did X, or should I try to get majority of my answer from drupal.org?

The FAQ reports the following text.

> #### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

The answer reported in [How do I properly write an answer that references my blog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-do-i-properly-write-an-answer-that-references-my-blog) says that answers referring the OP's blogs are generally not down-voted if:

- You paraphrase the content of the linked item (possibly omitting details or examples)
- You identify the author (yourself, MSDN, etc)
- Someone could benefit from the answer without reading the linked item at all
- You include information to let the reader decide if clicking the link is worthwhile